# access NOT static field from static class

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   TextView textview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
      //other method,startservice()and so on.

      //and there is BroadcastReceiver to receive a flag from service.
      public static class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

      @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intents) {
          intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          textview.setText("set");
```

here is my code.
all I want is  textview.setText() onReceive.

My first try, textview was static. 
But static variable seem to be killed during another method is running.
textview was set null, cant settext.

So i try to get textview as NOT static.
but there is second problem.
when i do that, i must get new MainActivity()  To access textview.
This didnt work well.complicated.

How can l get textview from static method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access non-static variable/method within static method because the static method exists *regardless* if there is instance of your class or no

You can maintain a static instance of your MainActivity (initialize it in the constructor or in `onCreate`) and use it to access the `textview`

For example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static MainActivity instance;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      instance = this;
    }

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intents) {
     instance.textview.setText("set");     
}
```

I do not know what you are trying to achieve here or when this `onReceive` will be called, but having static class for `BroadcastReceiver` does not seem to be good.

Another thing you will need to update the `textview` from the `UI thread` which you can do using `runOnUiThread`

```
instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // update your textview             
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!i know having static broadcast is not good. But when onReceive is called, it needs to be static. I consider to have broadcastreceiver class as other compile file, then gotta  be  more complicated to settext. If you have time, please teach me how.

Comment: Why `BroadcastReceiver` needs to be static? it should not be the case in general